# Overloading >> operator

Tags: c++, stack, operator-overloading

My task is to overload >> and << operators on Stack. They should work like pop and push. So it should look like that

```
stack << 4.0 << 5.0; // here I pushed two elements
float x, y, z;
stack >> x >> y >> z; //here pop 3 elements to x,y,z
```

I was told to use array implementation of stack and for << works when I just recalled push.

```
float pop (){
    if(!empty()){   
    n--;
     return data[n+1];}
    }

void push (float x){
    if (n<MAX){
    data[n++]=x;    
    }else {
    cout<<"Overload!";}
    } 

Stack operator<<(float k){
    push(k);
    }

friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, Stack &ob);
```

Now outside of class I tried to define >>, but it's not working.

```
istream & operator>>(istream  &in, Stack &ob){
}
    in>>ob.pop();
    return in;
}
```

Could you give me any clue?

Comment: The `>>` operator should have a prototype almost identical to the `<<` operator. (Look at `stack >> x;` Where did you find the `istream`?)

Comment: You say you want `operator>>()` to allow expressions like `stack >> some_value` to pop an element.   The only `operator>>()` you have defined is one that ostensibly reads the stack from an input stream.   Which do you intend?

Comment: This is terrible way of using operator overloading. Not even this disconnects  original meaning, making code unreadable but also effectively destroys your stack (pops element) when you are writing it to stream. This side effect is dangerous and pbly somthing you really don't want to do.

Comment: when you do stream>>var , var must be lvalue, ob.pop() is not lvalue;

Comment: Ok. Don't know why I used istream.
Tried now different way:
 float friend operator>>(Stack s,float &k){
  k=s.pop();
  return k;
  }

Comment: @user224301 The istream variant still could make sense -- but in entirely different context, if you wanted to read a whole stack e. g. from cin: `Stack stack; cin >> stack;`. You'd then read several values from the stream and push them onto the internal stack representation. Actually, this is what you normally use the streaming operators for...

Comment: Oh, and have a close look at Richard Hodges answer: He returns the stack object as *reference*! You need to do the same, otherwise you return a copy and will get unexpected results if you push/pop more than once! With your new approach you mention in a comment before, you should declare it this way: friend Stack **&** operator>>(Stack **&** s, float& k) and return s instead of k!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Stack {
    static const int capacity = 10000;

    void push(float x) { data[sp++] = x; }

    float pop() { return data[--sp]; }

    float data[capacity];
    int sp = 0;
};

Stack &operator<<(Stack &s, float x) {
    s.push(x);
    return s;
}

Stack &operator>>(Stack &s, float &x) {
    x = s.pop();
    return s;
}

int main() {
    Stack stack;
    stack << 4.0 << 5.0 << 6.0;
    float x, y, z;
    stack >> x >> y >> z; //here pop 3 elements to x,y,z

    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
}
```